# Check service status remotely

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to grab the service status (running, stopped) remotely using the credentials of the user running my executable(winform).

Would WMI be the best method?

I need this query to work on windows(7,2003,2008,2012).Can someone point me in the right direction.

```
if (RemoteOSversion.Contains("Windows 7"))
{
    var Windows7Query = xdoc.Elements("OS").Elements("Windows7");
    foreach (var myServices in Windows7Query)
    {
        var ServicesQuery = myServices.Elements("Services");
        foreach (var ServiceName in ServicesQuery)
        {
            var ServiceOutput = ServiceName.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

ServiceOutput is the service name.  I need to check if this service is running/stopped remotely using the same credentials of the user running my exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's REALLY straightforward with WMI

```
var sc = new ServiceController(ServiceName, MachineName);
string result = sc.Status.ToString();
```

Comment: That's not using WMI.  The `ServiceController` class is separate, and this way is better as it doesn't rely on the RPC service that WMI relies on - which can report as "unavailable" even if it's running.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use WMI.

WMI has a query language called WQL, which is similar to to SQL. You can execute these in C# using the `System.Management` classes.

To work with WMI you need to add a reference to the `System.Management` assembly. Then you can set up a connection (i.e. `ManagementScope`) to the WMI Provider as follows:

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();

// If we are connecting to a remote host and want to
// connect as a different user, we need to set some options
//options.Username = 
//options.Password =
//options.Authority = 
//options.EnablePrivileges = 

// If we are connecting to a remote host, we need to specify the hostname:
//string providerPath = @"\\Hostname\root\CIMv2";
string providerPath = @"root\CIMv2";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(providerPath, options);
scope.Connect();
```

You can read more about WMI at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/querying-wmi) and work around at [working-with-windows-services-using-csharp-and-wmi](http://www.gkspk.com/view/programming/working-with-windows-services-using-csharp-and-wmi/).

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, as the links can become broken through being archived/moved by the site owners.  A summary should be provided, here, so this can serve as a reference to future users.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20126747)

Comment: Go for it @SaravananSachi !